# ExtJs tabbing in popup window

Tags: extjs, window, tabbing

My framework has the ExtJS pop up window with some text fields and buttons. I need to achieve the functionality of tabbing inside the popup window. using tab keys i need to focus the elements displayed in the window. But on tabbing of last element the focus should return to first element in the popup window.

Any api's in extjs helps to achieve this functionality?

Comment: what should i do to increase the rate?

Comment: very simple, check off the best answers to your previous questions.

Comment: is this accept  rate ok to get good answer?

Comment: much better :) but keep working on it. You can even accept your own answers in 24 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this resolved by adding a listener to first and last element in the popup window.

```
var firstElement = Ext.getCmp('firstEl');
var lastElement = Ext.getCmp('lastEl');
Ext.EventManager.addListener(
  firstElement.el,
  'keydown',
  function(e){
    var key = e.getKey();
    var shiftKey = e.shiftKey;
    if (shiftKey && key == e.TAB){
      e.stopEvent();
      lastElement.focus(true, 100);
    }
  }
);    

Ext.EventManager.addListener(
  lastElement.el,
  'keydown',
  function(e){
    var key = e.getKey();
    var shiftKey = e.shiftKey;
    if (!shiftKey && key == e.TAB){
      e.stopEvent();
      firstElement.focus(true, 100);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Hi Jai... can you look into the update I am posting above. The problem still persists in some scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution. It solved the problem for us... partially though. I would need a suggestion or two to help solve the problem in a generic way.

What if due to some condition the last button/element is disabled. In that case the event listener on that button will not work. In my case pressing 'tab' on the 'second' last element takes the focus to some other control instead of the first one as this specific button does not have a event listener bound.

If you have a modal popup window that is 'masking' the UI behind it, pressing 'tab' on the second last button takes the focus to some control behind the window. I believe this is an ExtJS bug.

You can do a quick test to verify this behavior:

1. Create a 'button' in the main view
2. Clicking that button should open a confirmation dialog (modal)
3. Once the window is open press tab multiple times and notice that the focus is given back to the button that launched the window in the first place.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

I am using ExtJS 4.1.0

Comment: You can write a listener for second last element and focus the first element in the window if the last element is disabled. Else focus the last element. i could not find any generic way to handle this.

secondLaseElement:
  listeners: {
    keydown: function(e) {
     if (lastelement disabled?) {
       focus(firstelement);
     } else {
       focus(lastelement);
     }
    }
  }

Comment: Thanks Jai. I will try and see if I can get a generic way to work. I will also file a bug with ExtJS.... focus going outside of a modal window is clearly a framework issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a listener for second last element and focus the first element in the window if the last element is disabled. Else focus the last element. i could not find any generic way to handle this.

```
 secondLaseElement: 
  listeners: {
    keydown: function(e) { 
      if (lastelement disabled?) { 
        focus(firstelement); 
      } else { 
        focus(lastelement); 
      } 
    }
  }
```